# Place items from right to left in gridLayout

Tags: android, right-to-left, android-gridlayout

I have a `GridLayout` in one of my layouts.
I want to place items from right to left, Which means I want to have cell(1,1) in top right of my layout.
I have tested these codes in `GridView` so far:

1- `android:gravity="right"`   and  `android:layout_gravity="right"`
but it doesn't work.

2- I also tested `android:layoutDirection="rtl"`

and it doesn't work too.
how can I place items from right to left?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a workaround

add this line to your `GridView` in XML:

```
android:rotationY="180"
```

then add the same line to your `GridView` item in XML:

```
android:rotationY="180"
```

Comment: It'll invert the DPad Key invent.

Answer (score 6):

You should use in the viewgroup

```
android:layoutDirection="locale"
```

and then in whatever item you have inside set the gravity like this:

```
android:gravity="start" # or end
```

I know this is an old question a just wanted to complete a more accurate answer for people finding this post

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;)