# Align gridlayout left to right and right to left dynamically

Tags: android, grid-layout, right-to-left, left-to-right

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opf7V.png)I would like to set up a gridlayout right to left and left to right dynamically. 
(the children of the gridlayout are buttons )
Does anyone know how to  do that?

Comment: what do you want to do? set gridlayout width to match parent and you are done

Comment: I want to set up a puzzle with buttons, if the user chose English I want the buttons to appear LTR if the user chose language that is written from LTR I would like the gridlayout (and the buttons ) to appear RTL

Comment: just upload the picture. the problem is that I would like to give the user to chose the language he want to play- so I cant consider only his language device because if he speaks Hebrew only the Hebrew settings is correct at this phone (RTL) but if the choose English in the app I would like him to see the buttons set LTR

Comment: you mean the whole gridlayout go to the right? or childeview in your gridlayout?

Comment: yes the buttons are letters : so I would like the user to see "hello" (each letter is a button) instead of "olleh" which that's what he see cause his language phone settings are on Hebrew

Comment: if you using API > 17 you can use `android:textDirection="rtl"`

Comment: thank you Mehran, but I'm looking for the code itself in the acrivitymain.java (so it will be dynamically changed)  not the XML file. any idea how to do that with code?

Comment: there is mirroring but not good. check if it suits your need.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Arab  like?

Then check this out [Place items from right to left in gridLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845714/place-items-from-right-to-left-in-gridlayout)

Seems that setting layoutDirection might not work, in that case, a workaround has been provided.

For the button text, you can set that in code using layoutDirection

Comment: it rotates the whole thing not just text.

Comment: Could you provide a picture? Do you want the text only, or the layout also? If the text only use the setLayoutDirection() method eg. `newButton.setLayoutDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);`

Comment: Hi Ephraim, That is perfect for me! but how can I write it by code ?(dynamically! and not in the xml file)

Comment: Which part? For the GridView rotation in XML use `gridLayout.setRotationY(180)` & `view.setRotationY(180)`. The rest for Layout Direction is above. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

A `GridLayout` dynamically is done by making your own `Adapter`, as it works for the `ListView`, with the `GridLayout` you can apply an `Adapter`. To give an example if you want your `GridLayout` to be right to left you order your data from highest to lowest, if you want it from left to right you order the opposite (lower to higher).

If you can add an image illustrating what you want to do and the code you have for your `GridLayout`.

I hope I've helped.